# flatten images with transparency in PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, postscript

How to flatten images in PDF files with transparency?

## convert PDF to PS (postscript)

```
pdftops input.pdf output.pdf.ps
```

If a PDF file contains eg. PNG files with alpha channel (transparency) the PDF is rendered/rasterized to an image and that is not a solution because then you lose the plain text in the file

Is there a tool (linux command line) to flatten images in PDF files with transparency?

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear why you want to do this. If you want PostScript then Ghostscript can produce PostScript for you from a PDF file (use the ps2write device). Obviously transparency will have to be rendered to an image, in which case the resolution is important. The default is 720 dpi which is probably higher than you might need.

Note that a PDF file can't contain a PNG, that's not a possible image type in PDF. A PNG would have to be stored as an image with a separate alpha.

Comment: I want to compress/optimize the PDF.. If the PDF is converted to an image then the plain text in the file is gone

Comment: Converting the transparent areas to images will not 'optimise' the PDF, you'll much more likely make it bigger. I'm not clear on whether you see it as a benefit that text will be converted to an image and gone. PDF files are generally created compressed. If you want to make the PDF file smaller, then downsample images (and possibly convert to grayscale), subset fonts etc. Its still not obvious to me what you want to achieve and why you think rendering transparent PDFs to images is desirable.

Comment: Also, if text is drawn using transparency, how do you propose to render it and still maintain the text ? (There is actually an answer to this, but its non-trivial and I don't know of any tool which would do it directly)

Comment: I use ghostscript to optimize all PDF files with `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dColorImageResolution=50 -dGrayImageResolution=50` and it works pretty well except if the PDF contains transparency.. Then the whole images is converted to an image..

Comment: *Then the PDF is converted to an image

Comment: That shouldn't convert transparency to images, that should only happen if you select a PDF version < 1.4 (no support for transparency in older revisions of PDF). Of course, you might be using an old version of Ghostscript...... The current version is 9.14

Comment: I am using the lastest version 9.14

Comment: Ah, I've just realised you're doing -dPDFSETTINGS. I suspect that screen probably converts everything to RGB, and the colour space conversion will probably result in the transparency being rendered. This is because the transparency result depends on the colour space used to do the blending, when converting spaces we need to render the transparency to the specified blending space, then convert that to the required space. One reason why I tell people not to use -dPDFSETTINGS. Try it without.

Comment: Flattening transparency always rasterizes the area of the perimeter of the transparent object. That's (as far as I can see) the only way to handle this issue. For tools, you might look what Enfocus or Callas Software have; I don't know whether their server products are ported to Linux, however.